# Reading ArrayList in Concurrent system

Tags: java, list, concurrency, arraylist

I have a simple `ArrayList` and I am feeding this `ArrayList` from multiple `Thread`s via Java concurrency. Each `Thread` will only read the same instance of this `ArrayList`. Is there any chance of error during the reading operation?

Comment: If the arraylist isn't changing I cannot think of any reason why there would be an issue because all the threads are doing is accessing the list and reading.

Comment: So you have multiple threads that are writing to the list concurrently? And they are reading from the list as well or your readers are all in separate threads?

Comment: @Perception the list has been populated fully before the concurrency launched and so the threads are only reading it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In that case no, you should not have any errors reading the list from multiple threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provided there are no more writes make it immutable using `Collections.unmodifiableList` and then forget about read issues.

Answer (score 7):

If the list is fully populated and always accessed in read-only by all the threads, you won't have a problem. If there is a write operation, then you need to synchronize all the accesses to the list, or to use a concurrent list (like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`).